# RedHat UBI 8 install expect package

Tags: docker, expect, systemd, rhel

I have `expect` script that I need to run under RedHat UBI 8 container. I'm trying to install expect via snap package manager, but I have problem starting snapd.
After issuing `systemctl enable --now snapd.socket` I get:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Can be `expect` installed into RedHat UBI 8 without snap?

My Dockerfile so far:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

RUN dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm -y && \
    dnf install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm -y && \
    dnf update -y && \
    dnf install -y wget && \
    wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/squashfs-tools-4.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm && \
    dnf install squashfs-tools-4.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm -y && \
    wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/bash-completion-2.7-5.el8.noarch.rpm && \
    dnf install -y bash-completion-2.7-5.el8.noarch.rpm && \
    dnf install snapd -y && \
    systemctl enable --now snapd.socket && \
    ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap && \
    snap install expect
```

Comment: `dnf` can fetch and install, so instead of separate `wget`, simply do `dnf install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/squashfs-tools-4.0-5.el6.x86_64.rpm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `expect` package is part of the base rhel 8 repositories. If your host has a valid RHEL subscription, your container should have access to all the RHEL 8 repositories, which means you can simply install `expect` inside the container:

```
dnf -y install expect
```

If you don't have a valid subscription, maybe just use a CentOS based image instead?

---

The simplest solution is either (a) use a base image without licensing encumbrances, or (b) buy a license for the software you're using. If your clients are unwilling to do either of those things, you do have some alternatives:

You could make the CentOS repository available under ubi.  Create a repo configuration pointing at the CentOS 8 repositories:

```
[centos8-base]
name = CentOS 8 Base OS
baseurl = http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
gpgcheck = 0
enabled = 0
```

And use this to install expect:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

COPY centos8.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/centos8.repo
RUN dnf -y --enablerepo=centos8-base install expect
```

Comment: Thanks, but our client wants to use only one base image and that's UBI 8 and we don't have any RHEL subscription.

Comment: @Jeef in `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:latest`, the command is still `dnf`. There is no `microdnf` command in that image.

Answer (score -1):

#### Update Aug 18 - 2021

Previous answer was correct however `dnf` has now been hanged to `microdnf`

so the command becomes:

```sh
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

COPY centos8.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/centos8.repo
RUN microdnf -y --enablerepo=centos8-base install expect
```

Comment: This seems like a good reason to *update* an existing answer rather than posting a new one. Also, I'm unsure about the accuracy of this answer; if I `docker pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:latest` and then run that image, there is no `microdnf` command available. It would be very unlike Red Hat to replace a core command like that mid-release, even in a container image.

Comment: I've double checked, the `microdnf` command is only available in the `ubi8/ubi-minimal` image. The regular `ubi8/ubi` image continues to use the full `dnf` command.